How do I find the footprint of the 1 Meter USGS DEM in a vector format?
I want to know, for a given bounding box, if 1 Meter USGS DEM data is available.
At the moment I am querying:
https://tnmaccess.nationalmap.gov/api/v1/products?bbox=-119.94995,39.10144,-119.9442,39.1051&prodFormats=GeoTIFF&outputFormat=JSON&datasets=Digital%20Elevation%20Model%20%28DEM%29%201%20meter

Which works most of the times. But sometimes returns a file that matches the given extent but has no actual data inside my given bounding box. Such as in the example above.
Here's an example with a different bounding box where the response file does contain the requested data
https://tnmaccess.nationalmap.gov/api/v1/products?bbox=-110.92524,43.19113,-110.91739,43.19654&prodFormats=GeoTIFF&outputFormat=JSON&datasets=Digital%20Elevation%20Model%20%28DEM%29%201%20meter 


Can you add an example of one that does work, so we can see what's missing in the failing example?

@Spacedman I did, in both cases the response contains links to files which are meant to have data in my bounding box. However, in the first case, if you read the files, there is no actual data in the requested bounding box

Yeah that's weird. The working one returns a description and link for the DEM, the failing one returns four items, two of which have titles relating to wild fires, and two to DEMs. The wild fire ones have "moreInfo" which relates to DEMs, but the GeoTiffs linked look like wild fire data (from the file name).  Might investigate more later...
